# Implementing IEnumerator without using 'yield return' in c#

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I'm new to C# programming, I was experimenting with iterators concept in C#. Here, I'm trying to display all the terms in a list, for that I'm trying different ways to obtain the results. In the below code, I'm using two classes ListIterator and ImplementList.

In the `ListIterator class` : I defined a `HashSet` and it uses `IEnumerator` to store the values. Here `GetEnumerator()` method returns the values in the list. GetEnumerator is implemented in the `ImplementList class` (other class). Finally, the list is displayed in the console.

```
public class ListIterator
{ 
   public void DisplayList()
   {
    HashSet<int> myhashSet = new HashSet<int> { 30, 4, 27, 35, 96, 34};
    IEnumerator<int> IE = myhashSet.GetEnumerator();
    while (IE.MoveNext())
      {
        int x = IE.Current;
        Console.Write("{0} ", x);
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

In the ImplementList class : `GetEnumerator()` is defined and it returns the list using `yield return x.`

```
public class ImplementList : IList<int>
  {
    private List<int> Mylist = new List<int>();
    public ImplementList() { }

    public void Add(int item) 
    { 
        Mylist.Add(item); 
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
      foreach (int x in Mylist)
        yield return x;
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to rewrite the `GetEnumerator()` without using `yield return`. And it should return all the values in a list. I tried using for loop as `for(int x=0; x<Mylist.Count; x++)`, but it doesn't return all the values in the list.

Is it possible to get all the values in the list without using `yield return` in IEnumerator

Comment: I know it is not efficient, but I just want to try it. Is it possible to implement without yield return??

Comment: [How Yield Return is implemented internally](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx)

Comment: If you really want to implement it manually without `yield` you may want to take a look at this [MSDN code example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implementing-the-e1708a24). But in real scenario it would probably be better to just `return MylList.GetEnumerator()` - much more clear and effective than both the `yield` and custom enumerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MoveNext()` is a method that is called over and over and every time it has to move to the next item. This means you can't implement it by simply using a `for` loop (unless you use `yield return`, which is pretty much the reason why `yield return` exists), you need to rewrite it so that each `MoveNext()` call executes just part of that loop.

Specifically, it would look like this:

```
class Enumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int i = -1;
    private ImplementList list;

    public Enumerator(ImplementList list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        i++;
        return i < list.myList.Count;
    }

    public int Current { get { return list.myList[i]; } }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public void Dispose() {}

    public void Reset() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

This way, every call to `MoveNext()` performs the `i++` and `i < list.Count` parts of the `for` loop.

Comment: Will that work with my for loop, I mean (for(int x=0; x<Mylist.count; x++))..

Comment: @GIRI You mean when `Mylist` is `ImplementList`? No, why would that use `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator`? You're just incrementing an integer.

Comment: So, when a GetEnumerator is invoked. How we are going to return the values?

Comment: @GIRI `GetEnumerator()` is invoked either when you use `foreach` or when you manually call it (though this is very rare in normal code). If you want to use your collection in a `for` loop, you should write [an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), and possibly also implement something like `IList<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: I'm a learner, can you please give a clear explanation. @svick

Comment: Now, I created and defined a class Enumerator. What changes should I make in GetEnumerator() method?? @svick